# How to create a strictly columnar display in Vim for a tab-separated file

Tags: vim

In vim, I'd like to display tab-separated files such that the tab stop is strictly respected, meaning that each individual column is strictly aligned. This requires any content that does not fit into the width of a tab to be truncated. For example, with a tab-stop of 8 I would like this:

```
the quick fox<TAB>brown<TAB>4 legs
dog<TAB>lazy<TAB>floppy ears
```

to be displayed as (first line (ruler) is for illustration purposes only)

```
#23456781234567812345678 <- ruler
the qui|brown  |4 legs |
dog    |lazy   |floppy |
```

I've looked around for *tab-separated* and keywords like *truncate* and *fold*, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `conceal` (added in 7.3; `:help conceal`).

```
:syntax match Entity "[^\t]\{8}\zs[^\t]*[\t\n]" conceal cchar=|
:set conceallevel=1
```

Adjust the `8` to taste, or wrap the syntax command with `exec` to insert `&ts` (or `&sts`).

Comment: Thanks! I've not yet been able to test it, need to install 7.3 first. But it definitely seems to be right on target.