# Improvement to custom tabular folding

Tags: vim

I previously asked this question [How to create a strictly columnar display in Vim for a tab-separated file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094823/how-to-create-a-strictly-columnar-display-in-vim-for-a-tab-separated-file) and got the following satisfactory answer:

```
:syntax match Entity "[^\t]\{8}\zs[^\t]*[\t\n]" conceal cchar=|
:set conceallevel=1
```

Now I would like to stick this in a function with the hardcoded value 8 made into a variable; I would also like to be able to call this on just a range of lines. I have tried in a completely naive way this:

```
function Tt(w)
  syntax match Entity "[^\t]\{" . a:w . "}\zs[^\t]*[\t\n]" conceal cchar=| 
  set conceallevel=1
endfunction
```

I know that this must be easy… help will be greatly appreciated. This from someone who loves vim, but has not been able to create the head space required for its scripting language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function! Tt(w) range
    let l:range_pattern = printf('\%%>%il\%%<%il', a:firstline-1, a:lastline+1)
    let l:full_pattern = printf('%s[^\t]\{%i}\zs[^\t]*[\t\n]', l:range_pattern, a:w)
    exe printf('syntax match Entity "%s" conceal cchar=|', l:full_pattern)
    set conceallevel=1
endf
```

Explanations:

- It uses the `range` keyword in order to handle the range manually. Please note that if no range is given at all when calling the function, then the range will be limited to the current line (use `:%call Tt(8)` for the whole file). If you don't want this feature, you can remove the `range` keyword, remove the first line and replace the second one by:

  ```
  let l:full_pattern = printf('[^\t]\{%i}\zs[^\t]*[\t\n]', a:w)
  ```
- The variable `l:range_pattern` stores the part of the pattern which will limit the range of the match; it uses the pattern atoms `\%>l` and `\%<l` for this purpose.
- In order to execute the full command `syntax match ....` which is given as a string (`printf()` returns strings), you have to use the the `:execute` command (`:exe` in short format), as suggested by Araxia in your initial question.
- As [Araxia suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8099947/3271687), you may also remove the function's argument `a:w`, and use `&ts` instead within the function code.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you, and indeed thanks again to Araxia as well. It works beautifully, and this is very useful for manual inspection of occassionally large tabular data.